# if entry is in database then discard insert operation and delete entry

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table which stores "active" users of some arbitrary facility. There is an insert operation for every time a particular user logs on and logs off. What I want to be able to do is as follows:

- Upon detection of an insert operation into the database, check if the username is already present in the MYSQL database.
- If the username is present, then do not insert and delete the existing entry.
- If the username is not present, then insert.

Is there any way to achieve this? I am fairly new to MYSQL so I apologize in advance if anything I've said doesn't make sense - just ask for my clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to be able to do is as follows:
>
> - Upon detection of an insert operation into the database, check if the    username is already present in the MYSQL database.

Yes, you can achieve this

> - If the username is present, then do not insert and delete the existing entry.

You can manually search the username, and do the condition-statement as you want.

> - If the username is not present, then insert.

Same thing.

Here's an example base from what you want:

```
--INPUT @Username

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM activeUsers WHERE Username = @Username) THEN

    DELETE FROM activeUsers WHERE Username = @Username

ELSE

    INSERT INTO activeUsers (columns...) VALUES (values)

END IF
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I were to add a couple more columns to the table for additional information, will your example still work? Or will it need to be altered?

Comment: It depends on the design of your tables and in your requirements. If we will still use `Username` as basis for not inserting new ones in the `activeUsers` table, then there will not be any problem.

Comment: Another question, if I'm inserting values from syslog-ng into the mysql database, then where exactly would i put your above configuration?

Comment: You said that `There is an insert operation for every time a particular user logs on and logs off.`, you might need to *tweak* that a bit.