# mysql queries before insert operation by syslog-ng

Tags: mysql, syslog, syslog-ng

I am using syslog-ng to parse some logs that I am receiving via a csv-parser. However, I want to achieve insert operations that are a bit more complex than the conventional insert using the "destination" option in syslog-ng. Currently, my destination into MYSQL from my syslog-ng conf file looks like this:

```
destination d_sql_test
{
sql(
type(mysql)
host('<host>') 
username('<user>')
password('<pass>')
database('<db_name>')
table('test')
columns('col1')
values('${val1}')
);
};
```

However, this simply just inserts the contents of val1 into the column col1. I want to be able to specify my insert "logic" as shown in the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192647/if-entry-is-in-database-then-discard-insert-operation-and-delete-entry).

I am unsure as to where to actually do this, and if it is even supported by syslog-ng

Comment: This question seems to be more about how to configure `syslog-ng` than programming.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think there would be a syslog-ng tag on SO if these kinds of questions weren't allowed.

Comment: There are tags for lots of off-topic things. This is a legacy from before SE was spread into so many different sites.

Comment: Then a suggestion of which site to post my question on would have been more helpful than your initial comment.

Comment: I voted to close it using the reason that will recommend ServerFault.com.

Comment: I just had a look at serverfault.com, there are hardly any syslog-ng questions related to mysql. I think my question is in the correct place.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly okay question to ask on SO.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/sql-interactions-syslog-ng.html) the only thing `syslog-ng` can do automatically is create, alter, and insert into the table. It sounds like you need to pipe to a script that implements your logic.

Comment: So to make this on-topic for SO, you should try to write that script. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you.

Comment: Would this not be achievable with mysql triggers?

Comment: You've not said what your logic is. You've not given any indication of the options you've considered nor why they do not meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this if you can somehow make the decision within syslog-ng.

- You could try to use an [in-list() filter](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/log-filter-and-route-log-messages-using-log-paths-flags-and-filters/filters/filter-functions) to check if the username is already listed in a file. If it is not then, you can send the log into the mysql destination, and also to another destination (possibly a program() destination) that updates the file containing the list of users, and reloads the syslog-ng to update the inlist filter.
- You can [write a syslog-ng template-function in Python](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/template-and-rewrite-format-modify-and-manipulate-log-messages/customize-message-format-using-macros-and-templates/template-functions-of-syslog-ng-ose) that implements the logic somehow, and for example sets a macro to 1 in the message if it should be sent to the database. Then you can use a filter for this macro in your log path with the mysql destination.
- Or if you can write a separate destination that does the work in Python: [Writing syslog-ng destinations in Python](https://syslog-ng.gitbooks.io/getting-started/content/chapters/chapter_5/section_1.html)

Also, you might want to post this question on the syslog-ng mailing list, where the developers notice it more easily.

Comment: first and second links are obsolete now.